# MVC - @Html.Dropdown not populating values from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm pretty new to MVC.

I'm trying to develop an MVC webpage. I'm trying to use @HtmlDropDownList(), which would have to populate values from my web.config, using  a ViewBag. The page is getting rendered with the correct values, however on the output screen, there is no output. The dropdown shows only empty values on screen. Can someone please help!

Webconfig code:

```
<add key="ddlStreams" value="Las Vegas|India|Australia"/>
```

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string reportTypes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ddlStreams"].ToString();
            ViewBag.ddlStreamsVB =  reportTypes.Split('|')
                .Select((value) => new SelectListItem { Value = value.ToString() });
            GetData getdata = new GetData();
            return View(getdata.GetDataFromTable());
        }
```

This is my view:

```
<div >
    <div class="form-control">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("Stream name")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlStreamsVB1", ViewBag.ddlStreamsVB as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

The rendered HTML on clicking on View source:

```
<div >
        <div class="form-control">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label for="Stream_name">Stream name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select id="ddlStreamsVB1" name="ddlStreamsVB1"><option value="Las Vegas"></option>
<option value="India"></option>
<option value="Australia"></option>
</select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

The final output :(
[Final output here!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odKL0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you are not setting Text prop of SelectListItem, update as below:

```
ViewBag.ddlStreamsVB =  reportTypes.Split('|')
            .Select((value) => new SelectListItem 
            { Value= value.ToString(),
             Text = value 
            });
```